# Python script cannot run from .desktop launcher

Tags: 16.04, launcher, shortcuts

I have a python script that works perfectly if I just run:

```
python3 script.py
```

If I make a `.desktop` shortcut, with the above command, the sidebar script is opened (the py file is a GUI) but then it closes and nothing happens.

It is true that the `script.py` file takes about 10 seconds to load the GUI, but it does work perfectly, while the shortcut just shows a python script running on the sidebar, then closes.

EDIT: 
      I tried to launch the shortcut in the terminal:

```
gtk-launch script.desktop
```

which gives

```
gtk-launch: no such application script.desktop
```

Comment: Issues with `.desktop` of script (python, shell ...) are the permissions; you have less permissions to run the script using a desktop shortcut than launching it with the terminal. That's due to permissions that the shortcut got

Comment: unfortunately the permissions are not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

First, my desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=My Application
Comment=My Application Comment :-)
Exec=/usr/local/script.py
Icon=/usr/local/script.py
Path=/usr/local
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Next, maks the script executable :

Make sure the first line of your file has **#!/usr/bin/env python**

Make it executable - **chmod +x script.py**

An alternative is to use the python command line in the desktop file

`Exec=python /usr/local/script.py`

Comment: I have this problem in 19.04 when trying to launch the latest version of wxGlade.  It makes no difference whether I prefix the command with python3 or not.  Both versions of the command work from the the command line.  Binary executables start up just fine from the desktop.